# React prop is not rendering link

Tags: json, reactjs

The following prop I am trying to pass is not clickable/directing to the specified link. I have created a JSON file separately. Below is my react component

```
 <div className="card-action">
                      <a href="#{project.link}">View me on Github</a>
                    </div>
```

this is what I have included in my JSON file

```
  "link": "https://github.com/wyncode/joshua_matthew_michaela_nicole"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render value of your prop, you need to put it in '{}' and not in double quotes.

Try this (and as your link in your json data is full url, the anchor '#' is useless here):

```js
<a href={project.link}>View me on Github</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked as well but for some reason, it is still not clickable on my site

Comment: Try to add `target="_blank"`.

Comment: @cuellarn it should be clickable, can you post code of whole source file?